# Can VS code change the color of extra "end"?

Tags: atom-editor, visual-studio-code

Atom has a setting/package that (while programming ruby) will change the text color of an "end" if it doesn't have a corresponding "def","do", or "if" block. (i.e purple "end" = good but white "end" = bad) Is this possible in VS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is known as balanced pair syntax highlighting.

Atom uses [Tree-sitter](http://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) for [its syntax highlighting](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-grammar/). Tree-sitter is a full parser using code in [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) which can most any programming language. The [Ruby grammar](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-ruby) is fairly big; I don't see the specialized block end formatting that you describe in a cursory glance, although I don't doubt that it's there somewhere.

Visual Studio Code uses its own [complex language server system](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) for syntax highlighting. **The [documentation for the Ruby language server claims](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby#user-content-language-server) that it indeed implements balanced pair highlighting**, so if it's not working for you, I'd recommend filing a [bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: Great Answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user10881682: You can upvote it with the button on the left, and mark it as the correct answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: I upvoted but I couldn't figure out how to mark it as answered. All I could do was comment. I don't have enough street cred so my upvotes don't count yet. I haven't asked or answered enough questions to reach the 15 point minimum.

Comment: @user10881682: See the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)